# Module_six_moves_urllib_parse object has no attribute urlparse when using plot.ly for Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter, plotly

I am running below code in Jupyter:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np

N = 100
random_x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
random_y0 = np.random.randn(N)+5
random_y1 = np.random.randn(N)
random_y2 = np.random.randn(N)-5

# Create traces
trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y0,
    mode = 'markers',
    name = 'markers'
)
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y1,
    mode = 'lines+markers',
    name = 'lines+markers'
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y2,
    mode = 'lines',
    name = 'lines'
)
data = [trace0, trace1, trace2]

# Plot and embed in ipython notebook!
py.iplot(data, filename='scatter-mode')
```

I got error result as:

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315:
>   SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI
>   (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this
>   platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS
>   certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more
>   information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
>   SNIMissingWarning
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>   InsecurePlatformWarning
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning:
>
> A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from
>   configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to
>   fail. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        34 
>        35 # Plot and embed in ipython notebook!
>   ---> 36 py.iplot(data, filename='scatter-mode')
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.pyc in
>   iplot(figure_or_data, **plot_options)
>       173         embed_options['height'] = str(embed_options['height']) + 'px'
>       174 
>   --> 175     return tools.embed(url, **embed_options)
>       176 
>       177
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/plotly/tools.pyc in
>   embed(file_owner_or_url, file_id, width, height)
>       407         else:
>       408             url = file_owner_or_url
>   --> 409         return PlotlyDisplay(url, width, height)
>       410     else:
>       411         if (get_config_defaults()['plotly_domain']
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/plotly/tools.pyc in **init**(self,
>   url, width, height)    1382         def **init**(self, url, width,
>   height):    1383             self.resource = url
>   -> 1384             self.embed_code = get_embed(url, width=width, height=height)    1385             super(PlotlyDisplay,
>   self).**init**(data=self.embed_code)    1386
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/plotly/tools.pyc in
>   get_embed(file_owner_or_url, file_id, width, height)
>       313                 "\nRun help on this function for more information."
>       314                 "".format(url, plotly_rest_url))
>   --> 315         urlsplit = six.moves.urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
>       316         file_owner = urlsplit.path.split('/')[1].split('~')[1]
>       317         file_id = urlsplit.path.split('/')[2]
>
> AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no
>   attribute 'urlparse'

I have tried everything to fix it via this thread

[Attribute Error trying to run Gmail API quickstart in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190604/attribute-error-trying-to-run-gmail-api-quickstart-in-python)

1. I did the `export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` and make sure I unset it first to blank (yes, that path exists on my Mac).
2. I updated `w3lib (1.13.0)` and `six (1.10.0)`
3. Jupyter 4.0.6 and Python 2.7.6

What else could go wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I picked a wrong kernel in Jupyter. So if it is PySpark kernel, it gave me error. If I use Python2 or Python3 kernel, it's fine.