# Gmail API Quickstart AttributeError in Python

Tags: python, macos, gmail-api

I'm trying to learn Gmail API with Python using Mac OSX.

I have a standard problem for this OS: the default installation of the "six" module  is loaded before the one that pip installed. [Google's solution](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#troubleshooting)(at the bottom of the page) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190604/attribute-error-trying-to-run-gmail-api-quickstart-in-python) don't work.

When I tried to perform Google's one, I haven't found file `~/.bashrc` on my computer, but I created that and tried to change PATH in both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_profile.pysave`. It still doesn't help.

What should I do to run the quickstart example on my OS X 10.11.3 with Python 2.7.10 or 3.4.4?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 76, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart.py", line 60, in main
    credentials = get_credentials()
  File "quickstart.py", line 48, in get_credentials
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/tools.py", line 199, in run_flow
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 2006, in step1_get_authorize_url
    return _update_query_params(self.auth_uri, query_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 490, in _update_query_params
    parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(uri)
AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlparse'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution i have found: Reinstall Python 2.7, restart terminal.

Answer (score 0):

From this [Python issues thread](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/100), it's a given workaround to set the system environment variable PYTHONPATH to point directly to pip's install directory and add:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

which was also suggested in this SO post - [Unable to upgrade python six package in mac osx 10.10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485741/unable-to-upgrade-python-six-package-in-mac-osx-10-10-2/29666702#29666702).

I hope that will work on your end.

Answer (score 0):

`--ignore-installed six`

I had the same problem and this worked for me.